# How to bundle non-version controlled images in Xcode's Resources folder?

Tags: ios, xcode

Here are the approaches we tried but did not work

- **Version control the images** - bloats up our git repo, not a good idea
- **Images on DropBox** - Whenever our designer adds an image on Dropbox it gets available to engineers, but the engineers then have to add the new image to their Resources manually.
- **Image folder on DB, link folder under Resources** - Same as above, but we add the folder under Resources, not the image files. However, the manual process of adding newly added images still remain.

What are the best practices you have followed?

Comment: @JasonCoco - This was my first option like I said, it bloats up the repo.

Comment: I know, and in my opinion, that's what you should do. If your git repo is so bloated with pictures that you, as a developer, don't want to use it, it gives you an idea about what your users will face working with your app. So, again IMHO, keeping them in your repo is the best choice.

Comment: @JasonCoco, it's the revisions of the images (and not the images) that cause the bloat - so it's an issue for devs, not users. Though your suggestion does not solve our objectives, but still thanks for sharing your opinion - it might help others with their projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding a Folder Reference instead of a group when adding it to your project and using DropBox to keep that folder up to date with your images ?

As a Folder Reference, it should always reflect the current state of the linked folder without the need to manually add each file as it is downloaded from DB.

After running a quick test, I found that adding Folder References and trying to use the images from there with **[UIImage imageNamed:@"fileName.png"]** doesn't find the actual image.
You have to actually include the relative path to your Folder Reference, like this:

```
UIImage * imageFromFolderReference = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FolderReferenceName/fileName.png"];
```

That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Till date, I hadn't paid much attention to the Folder reference option. Let me try it out

Comment: There seems to be a problem: I have Resources > Images (added as reference) > foo.png, and my code accesses images as `UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"`. The images fail to load. If I drag the image to Resources > foo.png, then it gets loaded. Am I missing something here?